# What is the best algorithm for a small polling mechanism?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing a small polling for products,which product could be polled by each user in 5 scores (which can increase later) for each of its  properties(like: Cleanliness and neatness , Services , location , Staff ). each score has an adjective (1:the worst, 2:bad , 3:good , 4:very good , 5:extraordinary).

for example a user can poll to one of the product like this:
CleanLiness and Neatness : 4 (very good)
Services : 3 (good)
location  : 1 (the worst)
Staff : 5 (extraordinary)

the average of this scores would be the score of product, and it will be decimal, for this example , it is 3.25 .

now i want to give a adjective to the product by this result(3.25), if it's point is under of the half like 3.25, it rounds to down( for this 3) and if it's point is equal and above the half like 3.7, it rounds to up( 4)

I'm wonder what is the best algorithm for this ?

my classs' design is like below:

```
public class Product
{}

public Class Poll
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int ProductId {get; set;}
  public Product Product {get; set;}
  public decimal Score {get; set}
  public string Adjective {get; set;}
  public ICollection<PollAttributes> Attributes {get; set;}

}

public class Attribute  // for the attribute like Services 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public ICollection<PollAttributes> Attributes {get; set;}
}

public Class PollAttributes
{
  public decimal score {get; set;}

  public int   AttributeId {get; set;}
  public Attribute{get; set;}

  public int   PollId {get; set;} 
  public Poll Poll {get; set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(score)) to get the value rounded to an integer value and have a Dictionary() holding the attribute values, such that you could do something like:

`poll.attribute = lookup[Convert.toInt32(Math.Round(score))];`

Comment: Just also bear in mind the "odd" default rounding behaviour of .NET: banker's rounding. It may not always give you the answer you expect. So I'd highly recommend using:
`Math.round(score, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`
as it will give you the rounding you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Averaging is easy: you just keep the count of people who have voted, and sum of scores for each parameter(Cleanness, Service,...).
Once voting is done, you get the average for each parameter by dividing the sum for that parameter by the count. Then you add up the 5 average scores and divide the sum by 5, to get an overall average for the product.

Now, you make a string array like this:

```
    String[] adj = {"Worst", "Acceptable", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"};
//let "score" be the product average score
double epsilon = 1e-8;
double score = 3.51;

int adj_index = (int)(score + epsilon);
if(score - adj_index >= 0.5){//the floating part was bigger than half
    adj_index++;
}
printf("Product is %s", adj[adj_index]);
```

Note that the existence of epsilon is very necessary because 3.99999999999999999 and 4.0 are considered the same so we need a precision parameter. In fact, double 4.0 can't be represented exactly as 4 all the time.